# /map topic in rviz2 says no map received though data is published to /map

Tags: ros2, rviz, map-server

I am trying to load a map in rviz. I have used map_server and that is working fine. Data is being published to the /map topic as well. When i try to subscribe to /map topic in rviz, it says no map received.
Please help!

Regards
Abhishek[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the QoS. The map server defaults to transient local - which is not compatible with other QoS profiles. Changing rviz2 to using the transient local QoS for that topic may solve your problem.